# Can't connect to SQL Server using odbcDriverconnect (RODBC)

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I have previously made a connection multiple times using RODBC's OdbcDriverconnect():

```
con    <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("driver={SQL Server};server=", srnm,";trusted_connection=true"))
```

Recently I keep getting the following error and I have no idea how to fix this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("driver={SQL Server};server=", srnm,  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 18, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SSL Security error
2: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("driver={SQL Server};server=", srnm,  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 1, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).
3: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("driver={SQL Server};server=", srnm,  :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be some certificate problem according to the following [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1435709-unable-to-establish-connection-to-database). As suggested verify fi the time on the computer is correct or if the certificate on the SQL server hasm't expired.

Comment: Did you enable encryption on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error because Security team had installed the latest TLS 1.2 (Transport Layer Security) which causes the problem in connection of database form R. So possible below steps can help you out.

*step: 1 Delete latest updated or installed TLS 1.2*

1. search regedit (registry Edit ) and open it.
2. go to location : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProvider\SCHANNEL\Protocol
3. Delete install TLS 1.2

Note:- In my case, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.2 was there so I Deleted all.

*step 2. Restart SQL Server*

1. search services and open it
2. select SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
3. Right-click and Restart it.

Try to connect from R, hopefully you able to connect.